# What are my information organizing software options if I demand privacy and freedom “as in free software”

Tags: mind-mapping

I am not interested in pictures or diagrams, though I don't mind them. I am not interested in something simple either. Wikis are not a bad example of what I have in mind, but I'm still searching.

Privacy implies no cloud account needed.

What information organizing software options are there if I demand privacy and freedom... "as in free software"? Use either application names or application class names.

Comment: The "free/dom as in free/dom" pun was intentional; as in intended.

Comment: See: [What is the best wiki to install and run locally?](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/4784/what-is-the-best-wiki-to-install-and-run-locally)

Comment: I understand that you probably don't know the answer, which is why you are asking, but "information organizing software options" is a bit vague.  Mind-maps are a possibility, but there are more structured (tree-like) options, and project planning is something else entirely. Can you tell us what kind of information you have? And, do you require features like search/sort/links between info items, etc? The more detail that you can give us, the better we can help you

Answer (score 1):

Don’t know if the question is valid or not but here goes my 5cents:

Freeplane (mind mapping tool) does not require any user info, and can work offline. It has tons of features (that I don’t use that much).

Disclaimer: I use freeplane occasionally but I’m not affiliated with it anyhow.